# prove p or q iff q or p in Lean

Tags: lean

Trying to do the chapter [3 exercises](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/propositions_and_proofs.html#exercises) in the lean documentation, but having a hard time understanding all the terminology as I know almost 0 about writing proofs. I want to learn more, but need some help.

I've just been trial and erroring trying to solve this example:

`example : p ∨ q ↔ q ∨ p := sorry`

not sure where to begin. Is there an answer key I'm missing with explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the explanations in TPIL aren't helpful, then proposition world of the natural number game might be better https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/xena/natural_number_game/. I have given a solution, but I'm not sure it will be that helpful if the explanations in TPIL aren't very helpful.

Here is a solution

```
example : p ∨ q ↔ q ∨ p := 
iff.intro
  (assume hpq : p ∨ q, or.elim hpq 
    (assume hp : p, or.inr hp)
    (assume hq : q, or.inl hq))
  (assume hqp : q ∨ p, or.elim hqp
    (assume hq : q, or.inr hq)
    (assume hp : p, or.inl hp))
```

`iff.intro` is what you have to use to prove an `iff`. It ask for two arguments, a proof of the left implication and a proof of the right implication.

To prove an implication `p -> q`, you usually have to write `assume hp : p,` and then prove `q` given the assumption `p`

If you have a proof of `p  q`, then you can use `or.elim` to split into the case `p` is true and the case `q` is true. The two arguments are `p -> [your goal]` and `q -> [your goal]`.

`or.inl` and `or.inr` are the tools to prove an `or` statement by either proving the left hand side or the right hand side.

Comment: https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/xena/natural_number_game/ ? Looks fun. This was very helpful. Much more succinct than the documentation.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, should have included a link.

Answer (score 1):

```
example : p ∨ q ↔ q ∨ p :=
 Iff.intro
  (fun h : p ∨ q => 
    h.elim 
      (fun hp => Or.inr hp)
      (fun hq => Or.inl hq))
  (fun h : q ∨ p =>
    h.elim 
      (fun hp => Or.inr hp)
      (fun hq => Or.inl hq))
```